# Firefox -moz-placeholder, not working

Tags: css, html, firefox

I can't get this placeholder to style correctly in Firefox 13.0.1

I have an input field with a placeholder:

```
<input class="textFieldLarge" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username" type="text" />
```

I have this CSS:

```
.textFieldLarge{
    width:400px;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;

    background:none;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border:solid 1px #BBB;

    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#333;
}

.textFieldLarge::-webkit-input-placeholder, .textFieldLarge:-moz-placeholder{
    font-style:italic;
    color:#BBB;
}
```

This should style the text field #333 and the placeholder #BBB italic. I have this working with chrome and IE but can't figure FF out.

**EDIT, FOUND THE PROBLEM THAT I APPLIED ::-webkit-input-placeholder AT THE SAME TIME**

Still would appreciate a fix, but I doubt possible as it works fine when both are applied separately. Not a real issue any more but a little annoying.

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox (http://jsfiddle.net/jqJq3/)

Comment: @j08691: Thanks, yes it does. I found the problem was because I was also applying the webkit pseudo at the same time. I will edit the question.

Comment: @j08691: http://jsfiddle.net/jqJq3/1/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If one part of a selector is invalid, then the whole selector will be invalidated.

Therefore, one needs to have two different rules for each of `-moz-` and `-webkit-`.

Comment: Thanks, well explained. Makes sense.

Comment: Excellent Answer. Thank You,

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since posting this question, but in addtition to Gerve's answer, one should use `::-moz-placeholder` for Firefox 19+: http://mzl.la/15FPlx6 and can add support for IE10 with `:-ms-input-placeholder`. So the final code will look like that:

```
.textFieldLarge::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-style:italic;
  color:#BBB;
} 

.textFieldLarge:-moz-placeholder {
  font-style:italic;
  color:#BBB;
}

.textFieldLarge::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  font-style:italic;
  color:#BBB;
}

.textFieldLarge:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE10 */
  font-style:italic;
  color:#BBB;
}
```